# Excel VBA - Remember Last Userform Textbox Cursor Focus

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 text boxes on an Excel VBA Userform, and when I switch away from the window (say, to do other work in a different program) and come back, I want the focus to be on the textbox I was last using.

I think this should be an obvious question to an experienced person, but I can't find a well-asked question about this topic anywhere. If anyone can direct me to a proper answer, give me a searchable topic, or a good piece of code, that would be golden. I'm a sponge, I'll take anything.

Thank you!
-Chris

Comment: you want to focus on the currently clicked textbox?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to easily this, there is no GotFocus event which is what you would need to restore the focus to the correct control.  Dipping into the API and using a SetwindowHooksEx+HCBT_ACTIVATE would probably be one way.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor focus is not an event in VBA, thus it is a bit tough to do it. **BUT** you can use the `_Change` event and remember the last changed `Textbox`, which is quite close to you want.

You need a public variable in a module, for the name of the last changed TextBox. Thus, the next time the Form is activated, you may use a simple `select case` and use `.SetFocus` to the corresponding name of the form. The code below works with two TextBoxes.

In the form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    strLastTb = "TextBox1"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    strLastTb = "TextBox2"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Select Case strLastTb
    Case "TextBox1"
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    Case "TextBox2"
        TextBox2.SetFocus
    End Select

End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public strLastTb As String
```

In general, you may create a function that concatenates `TextBox&Digit`, so you will not be required to write 100s lines if you have 50 `TextBoxes`. And it would be looking better.

Comment: `Change` obviously implies the box had focus, of course... but if the box had focus and wasn't changed, `strLastTb` won't be correct.

Comment: Unfortunately Activate will not sink if you switch to another application

Comment: @Mat'sMug & Alex K. - yup, you are right, I was thinking of the same, thus I have edited the answer. However, its almost the same :)

Comment: I would **strongly** advise *against* numbering controls, and using meaningful names for them, e.g. `CustomerNameBox`, `AccountIdBox`, etc. - and then use the form's `Controls` collection to retrieve the control by name, before calling `.SetFocus` on it; that avoids the `Select Case` *and* doesn't leave the maintainer wondering if the *customer name* box is supposed to be `TextBox12` or `TextBox8`.

Comment: Surely better to `Public LastTb As TextBox` / `set LastTb  = TextBox2` - but it still needs an event to trigger this and there isn't one.

Comment: @Mat's Mug - good points, I was thinking more of a quick and dirty solution. Then I thought it was too dirty, thus I have assumed the concatenation.

Comment: @Alex.K - yup, declaring the public as a TextBox is definitely a better idea 

Comment: I'm seeing your help guys. Thanks for the conversation, I am working on this stuff as we speak. Currently, I am trying it out and seeing how I can get it working. Good idea on the concatenation, and good thing I already named my textboxes. I love specificity if nothing else! Will let you know what I come up with on my end in a few.

Comment: I am thinking...Maybe if I were to call on the Windows process that handles active windows?

Comment: @Mat's Mug and Alex.K, looks Like I am stumped for now. I asked a good tech buddy how Windows would know if a window became active,  and he said it is through the COM services that this function serves. Although, what he said landed me later at Handles, of which Excel has one for a currently open window. Using a handle, I may create a selection event in which I can run the code posted above. My only other thought is WindowsAPI